# How is the passing a count variable ($#) get the reference of complete data?

Tags: perl

Below is my code:

```
sub print_list {
  $max = $_[0];
  for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++)
  {
    print "$i.  $list[$i][0]\t $list[$i][1]\n";
  }
}

# Declaring a 2-D Array, which is just an array of 1-D arrays

@list = ( ["vi   ", "Null"], ["emacs", "Null"], ["joe  ", "Null" ]);

$max = $#list + 1;

print "Initial Values\n";
print_list($max);

print "\n\n";
```

Output:-

```
 Initial Values 
 0. vi                 Null 
 1. emacs           Null 
 2. joe               Null
```

In the above piece of code, how did `$max` passed to a function get all the data available in the function?

Comment: This is a good example of why you should avoid global variables.

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `$max` into the function does not also pass the `@list` array into the function.  Prove this by passing nothing:

```
sub print_list {
  for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++)
  {
    print "$i.  $list[$i][0]\t $list[$i][1]\n";
  }
}

# Declaring a 2-D Array, which is just an array of 1-D arrays

@list = ( ["vi   ", "Null"], ["emacs", "Null"], ["joe  ", "Null" ]);

$max = $#list + 1;

print "Initial Values\n";
print_list();

print "\n\n";
```

The `@list` array variable is global.

[perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Pass-by-Reference)

Answer (score 1):

The `@list` data isn't being passed into the subroutine at all. You are accessing it through the same version of `@list` which is visible outside of the subroutine. Accessing variables that aren't passed into your subroutine is a really bad idea as your subroutine becomes too tightly-coupled the code that calls it. For example, in your code, `print_list` can only work on a variable called `@list`. If you passed the array into the subroutine, then its name wouldn't matter.

```
# I've renamed this as you're dealing with arrays, not lists
sub print_array {
  my $length = shift;
  my @array  = @_;

  for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    print "$i.  $array[$i][0]\t $array[$i][1]\n";
  }
}

my @editors = ( ["vi   ", "Null"], ["emacs", "Null"], ["joe  ", "Null" ]);
my $number_of_editors = @editors; # More readable than $#editors + 1

print_array($number_of_editors, @editors);
```

But you don't need to pass the array length into the subroutine at all.

```
# I've renamed this as you're dealing with arrays, not lists
sub print_array {
  my @array  = @_;

  for ($i = 0; $i < @array; $i++) {
    print "$i.  $array[$i][0]\t $array[$i][1]\n";
  }
}

my @editors = ( ["vi   ", "Null"], ["emacs", "Null"], ["joe  ", "Null" ]);

print_array(@editors);
```

As a final improvement, a `foreach` loop is almost always easier to follow than a C-style `for` loop

```
# I've renamed this as you're dealing with arrays, not lists
sub print_array {
  my @array  = @_;

  foreach (0 .. $#array) {
    print "$_.  $array[$_][0]\t $array[$_][1]\n";
  }
}
```